# Is it possible to parse a string as if it's surrounded by << and >> in Raku?

Tags: raku

I'd like to reuse the parsing logic of `<< ... >>` on a string to get back a list as a result. Say, I already have the string in a variable, `$input`, how can I parse it without using `EVAL` (e.g., `EVAL "<< $input >>"`)?

A more general question from this is perhaps: How can I reuse any of the parsing logic used by various quoting constructs (e.g., `qqww:v:!c`)?

Answer (score 5):

For your particular example you *could* use [`val`](https://docs.raku.org/routine/val):

```
my $a = 42;
say << $a b c       >>.perl;       # (IntStr.new(42, "42"), "b", "c")
say ("$a", "b", "c")>>.&val.perl;  # same
say << "$a b" c     >>.perl;       # ("42 b", "c")
say ("$a b", "c"   )>>.&val.perl;  # same
```

But you'd have to know about `val`.

> I'd like to reuse the parsing logic of `<< ... >>` on a string to get back a list as a result.

You could spelunk the Rakudo compiler's source code to zoom in on what function is getting called. Thus you might discover that `val` is the relevant function for your example.

Parsing of language constructs starts with [Grammar.nqp](https://github.com/rakudo/rakudo/blob/master/src/Perl6/Grammar.nqp).

An in-page search for `<<` yields a LOT of matches. I happen to know that the  `<< ... >>` construct is a "circumfix" operator. So a few seconds later I'm at [the line in Grammar.nqp where its parsing starts](https://github.com/rakudo/rakudo/blob/master/src/Perl6/Grammar.nqp#L3585). Reformatted onto several lines the line boils down to

```
token circumfix:sym«<< >>» {

  :dba('shell-quote words')

  '<<' ~ '>>'

  <nibble(
    self.quote_lang(
      self.slang_grammar('Quote'),
      "<<", ">>", ['qq', 'ww', 'v']
    )
  )>

}
```

The trail then immediately goes cold. There's a `quote_lang` method in the same source file but it's clearly too high level. Where is `slang_grammar` defined?

If you encounter such a dead end the next place to look is [NQP](https://github.com/perl6/nqp). And sure enough we find [matches there](https://github.com/perl6/nqp/search?q=slang_grammar&unscoped_q=slang_grammar).

But now what? Really, this is all far too complicated.

> A more general question from this is perhaps: How can I reuse any of the parsing logic used by various quoting constructs (e.g., `qqww:v:!c`)?

Indeed.

Another route, often better that spelunking the source code, is to read the doc. But in this case I'm not finding an obvious path from `qq:ww:v` to `val`.

Which leads to a third route -- post an SO question. :)

---

This answer is... incomplete. But I'm going to publish it as is anyway in the hope it's helpful and/or I'll have time to improve it tonight or tomorrow. Or, better still, maybe someone has a better answer.

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate your help and effort. The amount of syntax and features in Raku make it a rich and powerful language, but also very complex. I know the grammar for parsing the Q lang is probably in Grammar.nqp, but that file has 5000+ lines..., and I've yet to learn Grammar and NQP.

Comment: cowbaymoo : the `QGrammar` is found here: https://github.com/rakudo/rakudo/blob/830400f5a8e3e2f0c20891e978b740b5f2a5c385/src/Perl6/Grammar.nqp#L5319